# PHP 7.1 - Build associative Multidimensional Array from sql query

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have a sql server table, VATTable like this:

```
VatCode     |   VATRate     |   Description         |  Active
00              0               VAT Rate 0.00%        1
04              4               VAT Rate 4.00%        1
06              6               VAT Rate 6.00%        1
...
21              21              VAT Rate 21.00%       1
....
```

with this query

```
$query = "SELECT VatCode, VatRate, Description, 0 as Goods, 0 as eFees, 0 as pFees, 0 as sFees, 0 as VAT, 0 as Total from VATTable where active=1";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
```

I need to build a multidimensional array with such data, that looks like this:

```
$VATTable = array
(
    '04'=> array(
        'VATRate'=>'4',
        'Desc'=>'VAT 4.00%',
        'Goods'=>0,
        'eFees'=>0,
        'pFees'=>0,
        'sFees'=>0,
        'Taxable'=>0,
        'VAT'=>0,
        'Total'=>0          
    ),
    '06'=> array(
        'VATRate'=>'06',
        'Desc'=>'VAT 6.00%',
        'Goods'=>0,
        'eFees'=>0,
        'pFees'=>0,
        'sFees'=>0,
        'Taxable'=>0,
        'VAT'=>0,
        'Total'=>0          
    ),
    '10'=> array(
        'VATRate'=>'10',
        'Desc'=>'VAT 10.00%',
        'Goods'=>0,
        'eFees'=>0,
        'pFees'=>0,
        'sFees'=>0,
        'Taxable'=>0,
        'VAT'=>0,
        'Total'=>0          
    )
);
```

so to be able to  manage it in the following way:

```
$vatCode='10';
$VATTable[$vatCode]['Goods']=15;
echo $VATTable[$vatCode]['Desc'].': '.$VATTable[$vatCode]['Goods'];
```

although my php knowledge is poor I think I have first to build the inner array and then use array_push to add to VATTable Array, but while searching for such solution, 
I found some example where I understood (??) that perhaps this can be done while fetching the recordset, and I thought I could do in this way:
        $VATTable = array();

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
   $VATTable[$row['VATCode']]['VATRate']=$row['VATRate'];
   $VATTable[$row['VATCode']]['Desc']=$row['Description'];
   $VATTable[$row['VATCode']]['Goods']=$row['Goods'];
};
```

but it does not work.

can suggest solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
   $id = $row['VATCode'];
   $VATTable[$id] = [
      'VATRate' => $row['VATRate'],
      'Desc' => $row['Description'],
      'Goods' => $row['Goods'],
}

print_r($VATTable);
```

Also, you don't need the word "array" in php7.
You can use

```
$VATTable[$id] = [ ... ]
```

instead of

```
$VATTable[$id] = array( ... );
```

If  you don't want to hardcode indexes:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
   $id = $row['VATCode'];
   $VATTable[$id] = $row;
   unset($VATTable[$id]['VATCode']);
}
```

Comment: yes, seen array is not required, but since it was not working.. tested also with old notation..

your solution is more compact although can avoid a further row, but that's easy also for me.
since fields are few this solution is OK for this example, but what if have large number of fields and want to avoid hard coding indexes?

Comment: Previous answer was clear.. for this have to learn a lot, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
      $tempVariable = array (
        'VATRate'=>$row['VATRate'],
        'Desc'   =>$row['Description'],
        'Goods'  =>$row['Goods'],
        'eFees'  =>$row['eFees'],
        'pFees'  =>$row['pFees'],
        'sFees'  =>$row['sFees'],
        'Taxable'=>$row['Taxable'],
        'VAT'    =>$row['VAT'],
        'Total'  =>$row['Total']  
     ); 
 $VATTable[$row['VatCode']] = $tempVariable;
};
```

Now $VATTable contains your multidimensional array

Comment: yes, both works well, but what about avoid hard coding indexes and having arbitrary number of fields?